# delete files older than 90 days using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete `*.sql` files older than 90 days using batch file and I wrote following command.

```
forfiles /M *.sql /d -90 /c "cmd /c del @file
```

I am not sure above command is valid? and if not need suggestions.

Comment: If you're not sure then why not test it?

Comment: Make sure to run your test in a sandbox folder with files you don't necessarily care about disappearing...

Comment: To expand on Mechaflash, just replace `del` with `echo` and check to see if the files returned matches what you expect. Then you know it works.

Answer (score 0):

> forfiles /M *.sql /d -90 /c "cmd /c del @file

```
SYNTAX (FOR WIN XP FORFILES RESOURCE KIT)
FORFILES [-p Path] [-m Mask] [-s] [-c Command] [-d [+ | -] {dd/MM/yyyy | dd}]
```

You haven't specified a path, so it will default to your current directory. Also, you didn't close out the quotes at the end of your command. For the sake of safety, I would specify your path.

> forfiles -p"C:\Path\To\sqlfiles" -m *.sql -d-90 -c"cmd /c del @FILE"

For your example, not specifying a path:

> forfiles -m *.sql -d-90 /c"cmd /c del @FILE"

EDIT: Edited my command as using `/` instead of `-` for the switch symbols doesn't work. Removed the link as well because it stated otherwise. Please note: do not insert spaces between the switch and inputs as it will fail. Also, your `@` parameter must be in all caps. Also to note, the online documentation on ss64.com is incorrect for the usage of `@PATH`

Comment: I suspect Zohaib is intentionally defaulting to the default directory - nothing wrong with that. If you specify a path with the /P option, then you had better use `@PATH` instead of `@FILE` in the command.

Comment: @dbenham I tested it with path and it gives me only the path of the file and doesn't include the file. If I use @FILE while specifying a directory with the `p` switch it works.

Comment: Say what??? On Vista, `@PATH` gives full path, including file name. `@FILE` gives file name and extension only, even if the /P option was used. So your version with the /P option and `@FILE` will not work on Vista unless the specified path matches the current directory. I'm not sure how FORFILES behaves on other versions of Windows.

Comment: ahh I'm on xp. It seems the output is different. In XP it doesn't like `/` for the switch symbols either. It takes `-` instead.

Comment: FORFILES is not Win XP native. If you have one, you downloaded it from an additional package for sure. In this case, it would or would not follow Win FORFILES standard